# Findcontrol in Multiview nested in Formview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a multiview inside a formview:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:FormView ID="fvSpec" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" OnItemUpdating="fvSpec_ItemUpdating"
            OnItemInserting="fvSpec_ItemInserting" OnModeChanging="fvSpec_ModeChanging">
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
                   <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditProdType" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CommonID") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
```

When switching to edit mode, the dropdownlist need to be bound:

```
    protected void fvSpec_ModeChanging(object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
    {
        int tableID = int.Parse(ddlItems.SelectedValue);
        switch (e.NewMode)
        {
            case FormViewMode.Edit:
                fvSpec.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
                FillEditLists();                   
                BindFormView(tableID);
        }
     }

    private void FillEditLists()
    {
        MultiView MultiView1 = (MultiView)fvSpec.FindControl("MultiView1");
        View View1 = (View)MultiView1.FindControl("View1");

        //ddlEditProdType COMES BACK NULL
        DropDownList ddlEditProdType = (DropDownList)View1.FindControl("ddlEditProdType"); 
        //bind ddl here          
    }
```

The formview control is found just fine.
The multiview control is found just fine.
The view control is found just fine.
**But when the dropdownlist line is executed, it comes back NULL**.
(object ref error)

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why it was not finding the control.
The formview needed to be bound first, then find that certain control.

```
                BindFormView(tableID);
                FillEditLists();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id) 
{ 
    if (root.ID == id)
    { 
        return root; 
    } 

    foreach (Control c in root.Controls) 
    { 
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id); 
        if (t != null) 
        { 
            return t; 
        } 
    } 

    return null; 
}
```

Comes from [this CodingHorror article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html). I'm kind of surprised we're on .NET 4.0 and Microsoft hasn't built something like this in yet...I use it a lot.